# Wi-fi not able to connect Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I am not able to connect to wi-fi in Ubuntu 13.10 after booting up after a month. I got to the wifi option in the top toolbar but it says ethernet disconnected although I have wireless on my laptop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had my laptop give me ethernet status before wifi status also. Is wifi just a little further down? I had to think & look twice! :)

Comment: So what do I do? It is actually a dual boot and the wifi is not working on windows either.

Comment: Obviously my idea is NOT your problem. Sorry. I was thinking you were talking about the wireless icon in the menu bar of the GUI. I have clicked it before (this is where you connect/disconnect) and found it showing the ethernet first, usually mine shows wifi first. Your problem is  not so simple and if it effects both winderz & ubuntu it is not something I can be helpful with. Sorry, good luck.